# XUL vs FLEX vs XAML

Tags: xaml, flex4, xul

Is there a updated comparison according to the latest technologies offered as shown [here](http://www.surfmind.com/musings/2004/03/31/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - [this is more recent](http://www.scriptol.com/ajax/ajax-xul-xaml.php).